# Using the Between Operator for negative numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsqlt

Why does using the between operator for positive numbers work, and yet for negative numbers it doesn't?

```
select case when 1.25 between 1 and 2 then 'Works'else 'no' end --- returns WORKS

select case when -1.25 between -1 and -2 then 'works' else 'no' end -- Returns NO
```

Comment: Because `BETWEEN` needs the range in order, and `-1` is greater than `-2`. Instead of `BETWEEN`, consider just writing out comparison operators to prevent such surprises.

Comment: Interesting, another reason to skip the `BETWEEN`. All mentioned here: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: Does SQL Server support `BETWEEN ASYMMETRIC`? Then you don't have to bother in which order you specify the arguments.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, ANSI/ISO SQL feature T461 "Symmetric BETWEEN predicate". Very convenient when you want to "between compare" columns instead of literals, and you don't know which column has the smaller/larger value.

Comment: @JeroenMostert that comment is better than all the current answers. You should elevate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select case when -1.25 between -2 and -1 then 'works' else 'no' end -- Returns works
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below: 
you need to compare with float value like 1.0 or 2.0 and range should be in proper order , min val will be first and then max val for example -2.0 first as it is minimum then -1.0

```
select case when 1.25 between 1.0 and 2.0 then 'Works' else 'no' end 

select case when -1.25 between -2.0 and -1.0 then 'works' else 'no' end
```

Answer (score 1):

Negative values grows from -2 to -1. Of course, `test_expression`, `begin_expression`, and `end_expression` in `BETWEEN` must have the same data type.

So you must use this:

```
select case when 1.25 between 1.0 and 2.0 then 'Works' else 'no' end -- returns WORKS
select case when -1.25 between -2.0 and -1.0 then 'works' else 'no' end -- Returns WORKS
```